# What is EAV model in database design? how it works?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-attribute-value

I am working on a project where we decided to use EAV (Entity-attribute-value) model to store category specifications and its values for products.

Please help me in understanding this to design a flexible database in MySQL!

Answer (score 1):

In [Entity Value attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), the attributes and their values are entered as rows instead of columns, and I quote:

> The basic idea is to store attributes, and their corresponding values,
>   as rows in a single table.
>
> Typically the table has at least three columns: entity, attribute, and
>   value. Though if there is only a single relevant entity, e.g. a table
>   for application configuration or option settings, the entity column
>   can be excluded.

So for example, for your case:

> model to store category specifications and its values for products,

You can do this

Categories

- CategoryId
- CategoryName

CategoriesMetadata

- Id,
- FieldDataType,
- FieldName,
- FieldDisplayName,
- FieldDefaultValue,
- Etc ....

This way the user has the ability to define the attributes, their data types, their names, and default values if any. Keep in mind that you might need extra columns, for exmample if you want to define combo boxes or lists, you might need another table to define the lists.

**Note that:** This model is to complex and you might need to make sure that you really need to go with it and there is no other alternative for your scenarios.

See these links:

- [Using Database Metadata and its Semantics to Generate Automatic and Dynamic Web Entry Forms](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2007/WCECS2007_pp654-658.pdf).
- [Planning and Implementing a Metadata-Driven Digital Repository](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/handle/10125/337/0409CCQPlanningImplementing.pdf?sequence=1)